# Django : How to access current logged in user's id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I have defined a get_queryset method in a viewset.

```
class BooksViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthorizedToAccess, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Books.objects.all();
        return queryset
```

Using javascript i want to display books of current user on one side and books of other all users on right side.
I did all the code but could not access the current user id in my js file.

```
if(auther.id == "current user id")
{
}
```

I Want to access the user id like this. 
For all search i did , i got to know about adding this user id as a hidden field or passing this id .But i cant as the method only allows to return the queryset object.

Can anyone please help me understand this.

EDIT:**MY SOLUTION**

In my views , i define the get_context_data method.

```
 def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(class_name, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx["author_id"]=self.request.user.id
    return ctx
```

In my template,i defined a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userId" value={{author_id}}>
```

And in my JS:

var x=  document.getElementById("author_id").value;

Comment: I think you could add the user id to the context

Comment: @JonasGrumann Can you please explain what do you mean by context.

Comment: In the first example he's adding a number to the context, so it will be available in the template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/

Comment: Is it ok to use get_queryset and get_context_data methods together in a ReadOnlyModelViewSet

Comment: @JonasGrumann thank you so much.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes.I have added a section "My Solution" in th question for future ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template tag as well. Like {{author.id}}
You can also assign to a javascript variable the value and then use it

```
var id = {{ author.id }}
```

Comment: What if my js is not in my template. It is a separate file and i have included it in my template.

Comment: thnank you  @stefano

Comment: Create a function where you can pass the id, then you can call yourFunction({{author.id}});

Answer (score 22):

As of Django 2.1, a new built in template tag has been introduced specifically for this use case: json_script.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

The new tag will safely serialize template values and protects against XSS.

It is not necessary to set any context variables as the request.user is already included in every view:

**template.html**

```
{{ request.user.id|json_script:"user_id" }}
```

**script.js**

```
const user_id = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_id').textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript is in your template file, you can access it like any other like this:

```
{% for author in authors %}
    if('{{author.id}}' == "current user id")
    {
    }

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I was trying the same ,but my js file is not in my template, i have included it.