# Accessing Django username in PayPal transaction

Tags: javascript, django, paypal

I would appreciate any insight as to whether it is possible to access the username of whoever is logged into my Django app from a PayPal smart button.
I currently have a "description" string within the createOrder function, which I would like to include the username.
TIA for any help.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62592463/2069605

Comment: Still new to Django, so had a bit of trouble implementing, but eventually got working exactly how I had hoped. Thank you so much. Still figuring out Stack Overflow too, but if you'd like to add that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept. Thanks again!